# Heliox saturation diving excursions nitrogen levels in Breathing gas medium

Tags: scuba-diving

The main question is on of effect of changing the composition of breathing gas mixture.
When breathing a mixture 10% Oxygen 8% nitrogen and 82% Helium at saturated levels, will there be an effect if we swap to 10% 0.5% Nitrogen 89% Helium as a breathing medium for 8 hours with upward excursions of up to 1.4b differential?
My argument is it would be more beneficial to maintain levels as constant as possible to avoid diffusion and counter diffusion during extended changes either + or - 1.4 bar changes during saturation dives involving changes in storage depth during a saturation dive.

Comment: What are you actual considerations for effectively replacing nitrogen with helium (heliox instead of trimix?) 
The helium penalty is discussed e.g. here: https://www.shearwater.com/monthly-blog-posts/eliminating-helium-penalty/
nitrogen is added to trimix because of cost factor, so you want to have as much nitrogen as possible within your safety constraints

Comment: Heliox saturation diving so Ideally Helium and oxygen.
In the chamber envirnoment there is introduced Nitrogen form initial pressurisation ie 1 atmosphere aditional compressions using Pressure locks  We reclaim this gas in general oporations cleaning out Co2 and other contaminants this reclaimed gas can contain up to 700mb of N2 with a maximum of 800mb allowable. The reclaimed gas is  is used in Divers breathing gas in dives feeding a diver semi closed circuit system scrubbing out Co2 and adding Oxygen to maintain the required 5-800mb O2

Comment: Not really a SCUBA diving question;  certainly not recreational scuba.  Aren't most saturation dives with that gas profile about 100m/330ft and using "surface supplied" gas,  i.e. umbilicals?  This isn't really Self-Contained-Underwater-Breathing-Aparatus (SCUBA)

Answer (score -1):

No true but it is breathing gas from a pressure source so no difference in the technical question of physiologically effects of gas composition and decompression / pressure differential changes.bTissue saturation obviously is a factor that will differ as scuba is still in the gas uptake phase rather than saturated bug you can say saturation at baseline is one atmosphere as opposed to say 10 atmospheres.